# When dual monitor used with Nvidia Driver, Ubuntu restarts the desktop environment after waking up from suspend mode

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend

I am a new Ubuntu user. I use dual monitor and dual boot (Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.04). When I am on Ubuntu and I suspend the laptop, the laptop goes to suspend mode (the led is blinking). However, after I pressed the power button, it restarts the desktop environment without showing grub menu and all processes running before the suspend are killed.

The solutions suggested for similar problems which worked for other users didn't work for me:

- Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"` and `update grub`.
- Install `UKUU` and try a different kernel by downgrading or upgrading.
- Change Nvidia driver version from 430 to 390.
- Install `pm-utils` and edit the `logind.conf`.

After I tried all of them, firstly, I realized that if I use nouveau driver with dual monitor instead of using Nvidia 430.26 driver, the suspend mode works as expected.

I also decided to unplug my HDMI cable and disconnected the second monitor while using Nvidia 430.26 driver. Without using the second monitor, I could properly suspend my laptop by using shortcut keys or simply clicking the suspend button under the menu.

However, I still have the same problem while using a dual monitor with Nvidia drivers. I need help.

Here is my laptop's system configurations:

- **Laptop's Model:** MSI PE60 2QE
- **OS:** Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
- **OS Type:** 64-bit
- **Kernel:** x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-25-generic
- **Processor:** Intel® Core™ i7-5700HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8
- **Graphics:** GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
- **Nvidia Driver Version:** 430.26
- **Memory:** 16 GB
- **GNOME version:** 3.28.2